# asos add products to basket

Tags: java, php, shopping-cart, bots

I'm trying to work out on the add to basket script so I could remotely add products to the basket of ASOS from my server.
There was an API a while ago but it got closed. It's not open anymore.
I'm thinking about developing a java bot. However, I'm still hoping for an easier solution.

EDIT: in brief what i want to know is how to simulate in php the "ADD TO BAG" button pressing process that will eventually add the item to the bag.

Comment: The questions is: how to press the button "add to basket" with php

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague. That said, if I understand you correctly, you want to emulate an enduser accessing the system from a web-form. You should simply check for the form's action attribute, and do an HTTP POST to that url with the post variables filled in.
Try to look at Selenium source code btw.

I'm also pretty sure that the system uses cookies for login, so don't forget to go to login page->authenticate->grab the cookies->send it back everytime you add something to your 'basket'.